# Tabbed Remote Desktop Client for Linux

Tags: linux, rdesktop

I use the rdesktop client to administer Windows machines from Linux.

Anyone know a program that will allow me to put these remote desktop sessions all under one window as tabs?

Comment: Oh, and I'm using Gnome / Ubuntu.  Would be okay with compiling though

Comment: +1 Good question. A tabbed RDP client would be really nice to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) is a GTK+ RDP client:

> Tabbed interface, optionally managed by groups

Has a Gnome panel applet, SSH tunnel support, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any RDP client that would do that out of the box BUT ...

Some more advanced window managers allow you to tab any windows together. For example, Fvwm can do it with [FvwmTabs](http://www.fvwm.org/documentation/manpages/unstable/FvwmTabs.php). My advise is for you to try [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) and its tabulous module. It could with a bit of configuration tab multiples rdesktop windows into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/) works under wine? I'm addicted to it for just that very reason (tabs) and it also does VNC, SSH and other fun stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[xEmbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmbed):
XEmbed allows the nesting of one application inside another application's window

Maybe you could use it to place many rdesktop windows inside a pygtk app.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [tsclient](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsclient/) in the past for bookmarking my rdesktop connections and I found it worked very well, but I cannot for the life of me recall whether it had a tabbed interface or not.

[Vinagre](http://projects.gnome.org/vinagre/) is probably exactly the UI-style that you want but it is VNC-only right now.

Answer (score 0):

RD Tabs! http://www.avianwaves.com/tech/tools/rdtabs/ this is for windows but its the best tabbed client I've ever used. He doesn't make one for linux becuase its a .NET Windows Forms App.

Best Linux clients are generally built into the OS you're running.

Answer (score -1):

I used PAC Manager for my everyday sysadmin tasks:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/